# Why do I get "Active: inactive (dead)" message Fedora Server?

Tags: networking, fedora

I have just installed Fedora24 server as a VM with 5 NICs. I have also assigned each NIC a static IP via ifcfg files

Issuing ifconfig , all NICs are displayed with their correct IPs

However , when I issue

```
systemctl status network.service
```

I get the first message

[image: First Message]

and when I issue

```
systemctl restart network.service
```

followed by:

```
systemctl status network.service
```

I get this message

[image: Second Message]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What's the output of *ip link show*?

Comment: Have you masked/disabled NetworkManager?

Comment: Marius 
Haven't checked that yet

Comment: Matt

I have tried with and without NM enabled ... same output

Comment: systemctl status network is networkd if oyu have not installed networkd you will get that  NetworkManager != networkd